# In Rails when using the Faker gem, Im unable to generate unique data. How to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faker

When I run `db:populate`, it gives the following error :

```
Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Nyaaid has already been taken
```

The email should be unique and the ID should be unique! Here's the validation for the nyaaid :

```
VALID_NYAAID_REGEX = /NYAA\/(N|O)\/(NP|WP|SP|CP|EP|NCP|UP|SGP|NWP)\d{4}\z/i
validates :nyaaid, format: { with: VALID_NYAAID_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Here's the Faker code, sample_data.rake :

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    Awardunit.create!(nyaaid: "NYAA/N/WP0001", name: "Test Unit", address: "No. 50, Kalpitiya Road, Maradana", district: "Colombo", contact: ["23232223"], email: "abc@localhost.com", insthead: "Namal Kaluaarachchi", instheadcontact: ["324234234"], datestarted: "1/10/2013", allowedmem: "5", remarks: "")

    @districts = ['Ampara', 'Anuradhapura', 'Badulla', 'Batticaloa', 'Colombo', 'Galle', 'Gampaha', 'Hambantota', 'Jaffna', 'Kalutara', 'Kandy', 'Kegalle', 'Kilinochchi', 'Kurunegala', 'Mannar', 'Matale', 'Matara', 'Moneragala', 'Mullaitivu', 'Nuwara Eliya', 'Polonnaruwa', 'Puttalama', 'Ratnapura', 'Trincomalee', 'Vavuniya']
    @allowedmem = Array(5..20)

    @from = 10.years.ago
    @to = Time.now

    def rand_date
      Time.at(@from + rand * (@to.to_f - @from.to_f)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    end

    @idarray = Array(2222..9999)

    def pickidarray
      id = @idarray.sample
      @idarray.delete(id)
      return id
    end

    50.times do |n|
      nyaaid = "NYAA/N/WP#{pickidarray}"
      name  = Faker::Company.name
      address = Faker::Address.street_address
      district = @districts.sample
      contact = Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
      email = "example-#{n+1}@slnyaa.org"
      insthead = Faker::Name.name
      instheadcontact = Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
      datestarted = rand_date
      allowedmem = @allowedmem.sample
      remarks = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(rand(1..2))
      Awardunit.create!(nyaaid: nyaaid, name: name, address: address, district: district, contact: contact, email: email, insthead: insthead, instheadcontact: instheadcontact, datestarted: datestarted, allowedmem: allowedmem, remarks: remarks)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems to me that `email` and `nyaaid`you are generating are unique. Maybe the db you are filling includes data that was previously inserted and creates conflicts? You can try putting `Awardunit.destroy_all` at the beginning of the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try

```
Awardunit.create!(nyaaid: "NYAA/N/WP0001", name: "Test Unit", address: "No. 50, Kalpitiya Road, Maradana", district: "Colombo", contact: ["23232223"], email: "abc@localhost.com", insthead: "Namal Kaluaarachchi", instheadcontact: ["324234234"], datestarted: "1/10/2013", allowedmem: "5", remarks: "")
```

add `Awardunit.destroy_all` before creating first object.